# Why are my WebLogic clustered MDB app deployments in warning state?

Tags: weblogic

I have a WebLogic cluster on which I've deployed numerous topics and applications that use them. My applications uniformly show themselves in a Warning status. Looking at Monitoring on the deployment, I see the MDB application connects to Server #1, but on server #2 it shows this:

```
MDB application appName is NOT connected to messaging system.
```

My JMS Server is targetted to a migratable target, which is in turn targetted to the #1 server and has a cluster identified. And messages sent to either server all flow as expected. I just don't know why these deployments show in a Warning state.

WebLogic 11g

Comment: Is the "appName" shown that of your application or an internal BEA MDB ? Does it go away after cluster restart?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and asking. AppName is the name of our application. Restarting the servers in the cluster had no effect on the error.

Comment: No exceptions at all such as "weblogic.rjvm.PeerGoneException" or a stack showing "weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl$HeartbeatMonitorListenerDeliverer.execute" ? And what happens if you were to test run only with Server 2?

Comment: Hmmm. No RJVM in thread dumps on either server. On node #1 only, I see this in the logs, but another admin was making big changes last night: ####Apr 29, 2010 7:07:59 PM EDT, Info, Cluster, <WLS Kernel> ====Removing node2 jvmid:-2957945179636271925S:server2:[8010,8010,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:DomainName:node2 from cluster view due to PeerGone. ####Apr 29, 2010 8:41:27 PM EDT, Info, Cluster, <WLS Kernel> ====Removing node2 jvmid:5941513196864295832S:server2:[8010,8010,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:DomainName:node2 from cluster view due to PeerGone.

Comment: I can't take down server one without impacting another team's work, but one of our team has seen node2 take up the load successfully when node1 is offline. Messages still transmit. I don't like delivering hearsay, but since messages transmitted directly to node2 right now travel successfully, there's a degree of confidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be avoided by using the parameter below

```
<start-mdbs-with-application>false</start-mdbs-with-application>
```

In the **weblogic-application.xml**, Setting start-mdbs-with-application to false forces MDBs to defer starting until after the server instance opens its listen port, near the end of the server boot up process.

If you want to perform startup tasks after JMS and JDBC services are available, but before applications and modules have been activated, you can select the Run Before Application Deployments option in the Administration Console (or set the StartupClassMBean’s LoadBeforeAppActivation attribute to “true”).

If you want to perform startup tasks before JMS and JDBC services are available, you can select the Run Before Application Activations option in the Administration Console (or set the StartupClassMBean’s LoadBeforeAppDeployments attribute to “true”).

Refer :http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ejb/message_beans.html
this is applicable for the versions till 12c and later

Answer (score 1):

I don't like unanswered questions, so I'm going to answer this one.

The problem is resolved, though I was not involved in its resolution. At present the problem only exists for the length of time it takes the JMS subsystem to fully initialize. During that period (with many queues, it can take a while) the JNDI system throws errors and the apps are truly in warning state. Once the JMS is fully initialized, everything goes green.

My belief is that someone corrected something in the JMS Server / Cluster config. I'll never know what it was.